# Oracle monitor tool

Tags: oracle, memory, monitoring

Our Oracle server continues with out of memory problem, and we don't have an Oracle DBA in our team. Is there any Oracle monitor tool or ways to find the reason?

We have a lot of stored procedure running by Oracle jobs, we thought may be the reason but not very sure about it.

Oracle run in Red hat Linux.When it is out of memory. Enter free -m, it can seen there is almost nothing left in free space and or has been used.

[image]

I mean out of memory is that when i try to shutdown oracle, it return Out of memroy as shown below.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "out of memory" problem? Are you getting (a) certain error(s), and if so, which one(s)? Which OS? Do you have access to the server at OS level, or just via Oracle sessions? You'll need to add more information -- as it stands this question runs the risk of being closed as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Our server is linux.

Comment: You received the above error, because you connected to "nothing" (Connected to idle instance.), and not to the database. Set the environment variables (especially ORACLE_SID) properly. For understanding the output of `free -m`, I recommend this site: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ . That alone is not a problem. So what is your ACTUAL problem? Is the application/database slow? Do you encounter any errors in the application? Does the database crash any time?

Comment: Your `free -m` is showing 2.4Gb free. Do you understand @Balazs's comment above? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/349886/533832) too, and consider employing an Oracle DBA.

Comment: @BalazsPapp At that moment,the server is very very slow and our application is already dead.I have to kill oracle process,and then became fast.

Comment: @JackDouglas as you see the swap space is nothing left.when using toad to connect to oracle,it also return OUT of Memory error.

Comment: Yes I can see the swap is used, but I also see 2371Mb free memory. Do you see that?

Comment: I will increase swap space and physical memory,see if it will happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "Oracle Server", if you are trying to monitor physical (or virtual) server level statistics, you can make use of OSWatcher.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_oswatcher_diag.html

Note that this is really just a wrapper of stuff that should be available on any *nix type server. It will format outputs and produce readable graphs for you.

If you're actually saying that your Oracle Database instance(s) is/are running out of memory, then I highly recommend statspack and an independent Enterprise Manager solution, for ease of use especially since you state that you don't currently have a DBA on your team. Your comment above doesn't provide enough context for me to start troubleshooting that type of issue.

Comment: is statspack same as awr?

Answer (score 0):

if you have oracle Diagnostic and/or Tuning pack you can use some of these advisors, eg. by Oracle Enterprise Manager:

**Diagnostics Pack:**
Performance (tab)
ADDM

**Tuning Pack:**
SQL Access Advisor 
SQL Tuning Advisor

You can check this by running:

```
show parameter CONTROL_MANAGEMENT_PACK_ACCESS;
```

Some useful summary of advisors:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_advisor_central_addm.htm

Comment: NB Both the Diagnostics Pack and Tuning Pack require licenses to use them. If your team doesn't have a DBA, it's highly likely your organisation doesn't have licenses for these packs either.

Answer (score -2):

You have to increase the RAM size and the increase the SGA parameters.

I would suggest you to go through OTN: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2324835?tstart=0

Comment: Please explain how you get to that conclusion from the information provided. I'm not saying you're wrong, but as it is this is basically a comment, not an answer.